# How to send email alert when 2 SELECT COUNT statements from 2 different servers is not equal?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have two servers that must always be synchronized with one another. To monitor this, I have a query that I am using to check whether they are equal or not. This is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT (distinct filename) from DB.dbo.Table (nolock)
WHERE SentWhen > '2017-07-17 00:00:00'
```

I am having problems with regards to monitoring when we already have missed synchronizing the file/s. What I need is a script or a job that will send an email alert when the results of the query for both servers is not equal or their difference is not equal to 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I only see one DB here... and i'd be careful with that NOLOCK hint in this case... you can get dirty reads.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually, I run that script for both of my databases. If you have any insights, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can approach this. Though I'm still baffled at the db check with this query.

```
if
(SELECT COUNT (distinct filename) from DB.dbo.Table (nolock)
WHERE SentWhen > '2017-07-17 00:00:00') 
<> 
(SELECT COUNT (distinct filename) from DB2.dbo.Table (nolock)
WHERE SentWhen > '2017-07-17 00:00:00')
begin
...do something like send an email with sp_send_dbmail...
end
```

However, as I stated, I wouldn't count this as reliable especially with your `NOLOCK` hint, among other things. If these databases are written to quite often, race condidtions could happen, bandwith could come into play, etc...  But if you trust your method of declaring them as "in sync" based off that query, that's how you'd send an email..

Answer (score 0):

@scsimon Thanks for contributing some insights to my question! I really can't tweak the settings of the database since I'm not a DBA so what I did was to create the query that I need to check the difference between the distinct files coming in to both servers.

```
(SELECT (SELECT COUNT (Distinct FileName)
FROM [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Table] with (nolock)
WHERE CONVERT (varchar (19), SentWhen) > 'SpecifiedDate') 
- 
(SELECT COUNT (Distinct FileName)
FROM [OtherServer].[OtherDatabase].[dbo].[OtherTable] with (nolock)
WHERE CONVERT (varchar (19), SentWhen) > 'SpecifiedDate')  AS [Difference])
```

And a query that will give me the current count of the files for each server.

```
SELECT PrimarySite = (SELECT (SELECT COUNT (Distinct FileName)
FROM [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Table] with (nolock)
WHERE CONVERT (varchar (19), SentWhen) > 'SpecifiedDate')

SELECT SecondarySite = (SELECT (SELECT COUNT (Distinct FileName)
FROM [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Table] with (nolock)
WHERE CONVERT (varchar (19), SentWhen) > 'SpecifiedDate')
```

After this, I made a batch script that will execute this both queries (they are saved as different files) and put the results in seperate TXT files. Here's the script:

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -E -S Server\Database -i 
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileDiff.sql -h -1 > 
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileDiff.txt
set /p raw=< C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileDiff.txt
set /a value=raw
sqlcmd -E -S Server\Database -i 
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileCount.sql > 
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileCount.txt

IF %value% NEQ 0 (
    wscript C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\Notification.vbs
) ELSE (
    echo No discrepancy between the two sites.
)
```

What this batch script does is to execute both queries and and put their results into TXT files. For the FileDiff.txt, I had to remove the column header and the whitespaces to avoid errors in executing the IF statement. If the difference between both servers is not equal to 0, it will trigger the VBscript to send an email alert. What the VBscript does is, of course, to send an email notification that there is discrepancy between the distinct files of the servers and will parse the current count of distinct files for each server on the TXT file where the batch script is writing the results.

```
Option Explicit 

Dim arrLines, objShell, objFSO, strFiles, NumberOfFiles, objSubFolder, 
objFile, objReader, intAgeInMinutes, strDir, ToAddress, FromAddress, 
wshShell, strData, fso, count, src, folder, file, dateStamp, lday, lmonth, 
lyear, logdate, objFsoLog, logOutput, objFolder, filemodif, Message, 
Subject, cdoBasic

'Define file to scan
Const cBaseFile = "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FilesComparison\FileCount.txt"

'Constants for I/O
Const ForReading = 1

'Make sure the file exists
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFSO.FileExists(cBaseFile) Then
   Wscript.Echo "ERROR: file not found [" & cBaseFile & "]"
   Wscript.Quit
End If

Set objReader = objFSO.OpenTextFile(cBaseFile, ForReading)
strData = objReader.ReadAll
objReader.Close

'Split file data into an array breaking on end of lines
arrLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)

'Initialize the email notification
ToAddress = "Recipients of email notification"  
FromAddress = "Alert_FileCount@noreply.com"  'Sender (noreply) address

'Initialize the source server
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )


Sub emailSendCDOSYS()  
Dim Mailer  
Set Mailer=CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
Message = "===============================================" & VbCrLf  
Message = Message & "The File Count is not equal between two servers!" & VbCrLf  
Message = Message & "Date/Time: "& now() &"" & VbCrLf  
Message = Message & "===============================================" & 
VbCrLf & VbCrLf   
Message = Message & "Here is the current file count for:" & VbCrLf & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(0) & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(1) & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(2) & VbCrLf
Message = Message & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(3) & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(4) & VbCrLf
Message = Message & arrLines(5) & VbCrLf & VbCrLf
Message = Message & "Please do the following:" & VbCrLf
Message = Message & VbCrLf & "Step 1:" & VbCrLf
Message = Message & VbCrLf & "Step 2:" & VbCrLf
Message = Message & VbCrLf & "Step 3:" & VbCrLf

Subject = " File Count Discrepancy "
Mailer.TextBody = Message  
Mailer.Subject = Subject  
Mailer.To = ToAddress  
Mailer.From = FromAddress  

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2  

'set the SMTP server 
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.server.com" 

'SMTP port 
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25  

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Update 
Mailer.Send  
set Mailer = Nothing  
End Sub 


Call emailSendCDOSYS
```

Then I made a PowerShell script to execute the batch script in loop and in background.

It took me a long time to respond to this thread because there's so much to do this past few months. I posted this just in case there's someone like me out there who might need this work around. I still don't have enough reputation to make my vote publicly displayed, but I voted for you answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A long ago, We'd similar issue that, send email when amounts (from 2 tables) are different and we solved it. So I recreate our solution for you:

1). Login server.

2). [Create Email configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-sql-server-agent-mail-to-use-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017)

3). Write SP as like as,

```
create procedure sendMail 
as
begin
if server1.count <> server2.count
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'ProfileName',  
@recipients = 'client@gmail.com',  
@body = 'Server Alert',  
@subject = 'Server Alert' ;
end
```

4).  Create new Maintenance Plan. Find and drag and drop the **Execute T-SQL statement Task**, form **Tools**

5).Double click on task. And write,

```
use DBname
exec sendMail --what you created in step 2
```

6). Then schedule this job as your time wish.

7). Run manually at first time.

Hereafter, You'll receive a alert mail when counts are mismatched.